# Lower level execution than Bytecode

Tags: interpreter

I've been developing my own language now for about a year and I've been mostly focusing on getting exposure to all the different methodologies. My language is software interpreted so I spend a large amount of time familiarizing myself with new and lower level methods to interpret the code but now I'm stuck. I've gone from raw interpretation line by line to syntax trees and so on and I've gotten it down to the Bytecode stage.

I can't seem to find anything online about anything more processed down then Bytecode that isn't just creating an executable.

My language can also be compiled so I have machine code that I can generate and works so would there be anyway to inject that to be executed in packets or something?

I've been stuck on Bytecode execution for a few months now and the dragon book isn't helping in this regard.

Comment: The "intermediate" between bytecode and a plain executable would be a JIT. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Why the C++ tag? Did you look at existing examples like llvm or a jvm?

Comment: If you want to directly run compiled code without creating an executable *Ahead Of Time*, you need to focus on *Just In Time* compiling methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next step beyond a simple bytecode interpretation (likely it is a huge `switch` statement or something similar in your case), which can still be qualified as "interpretation" rather then "compilation", is to translate your bytecode into a direct threaded code.

An impressive example of this technique is the OCaml bytecode interpreter, see the code [here](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/byterun/interp.c). Note the different possible definitions of the `Instruct(...)` macro - it is used for both an ad hoc `switch` implementation and an optimised threaded code implementation, depending on an availability of the *computed goto* extension.

I doubt you can go any further down than this, anything lower level will be a "compilation" rather than "interpretation". Of course you can design a lower level virtual machine, define a sequence of transforms from a high level VM into a low level but yet an abstract one, etc.

Comment: Even better. This is exactly the kind of thing that I was looking for. Appreciate it a lot mate.

Comment: How does "go[ing] any further down" change building an interpreter to writing a compiler?  They're two totally different types of software engineering.  What does VMware have to do with Visual Studio?

Comment: @PaulEvans, the boundary between interpretation and compilation is a way too blurry, and the difference is elusive. With a bytecode interpreter, for example, you first *compile* your high level code into a virtual machine code. Then you have two options - either *simulate* this machine (which can be called "interpretation"), or translate (i.e., "*compile*") it further down to something closer to your host platform machine code. Threaded code seems to be on a verge of what "interpretation" is (but Forth folk won't agree).

Comment: @PaulEvans, and could you please explain, how VMware or Visual Studio could be relevant to this discussion?

Comment: An interpreter and a compiler are a lot alike and with a little effort I can convert my interpreter into a compiler. I would simply introducing one small step to turn my bytecode into the right assembly and spitting it out into and ELF or PE file with the proper headers, however this now makes the final product machine dependent. Since my language currently works for development on ARM and Intel devices along with others I want to avoid this. By "interpreting" I'm making it so the developer doesn't have to worry about different versions of the same program, it makes it my problem.

Comment: Of course I could do JIT compilation but this project is a thought experiment for school on pure interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a virtual machine that'll execute your Bytecode, similar to `Java`'s JVM.

Comment: So I would need to then feed the machine code I generate to the virtual machine? Is that how Java's JIT works?

Comment: Yes but the Bytecode, the virtual machine acts on the Bytecode much like the CPU acts on compiled code.